# command line curl stream output

Tags: curl, command-line, output

I run

curl -X POST 'http://172.24.0.40:4243/build?t=basejava8'

and get curl output

> {"stream":"Step 0 : FROM phusion/baseimage:0.9.16\n"} {"stream":"
>   ---\u003e 5a14c1498ff4\n"} {"stream":"Step 1 : CMD /sbin/my_init\n"} {"stream":" ---\u003e Using cache\n"} {"stream":" ---\u003e
>   9ca43c73f936\n"} {"stream":"Step 2 : RUN apt-get update \u0026\u0026
>   DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y
>   ca-certificates\n"} {"stream":" ---\u003e Using cache\n"} {"stream":"
>   ---\u003e b5dcbe0f1c27\n"} {"stream":"Step 3 : RUN echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true
>   | debconf-set-selections \u0026\u0026   add-apt-repository -y
>   ppa:webupd8team/java \u0026\u0026   apt-get update \u0026\u0026
>   apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer \u0026\u0026   apt-get
>   install -y oracle-java8-set-default \u0026\u0026   rm -rf
>   /var/lib/apt/lists/* \u0026\u0026   rm -rf
>   /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer\n"} {"stream":" ---\u003e Using
>   cache\n"} {"stream":" ---\u003e 4eaa2e3796a2\n"} {"stream":"Step 4 :
>   ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle\n"} {"stream":" ---\u003e
>   Using cache\n"} {"stream":" ---\u003e 5d8bfb398fb6\n"}
>   {"stream":"Successfully built 5d8bfb398fb6\n"}

Is it possible to avoid brackets and "stream" in output, i.e. as plain text via curl parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has nothing to do with `curl`: what you're seeing is what the service (in this case Docker) is actually giving you.

That said, while you could try to extract the value you want with a regex, I would recommend that you parse every line with a JSON parser instead. In your example, every line happens to look like `{"stream":"..."}`, but an example in the Docker API documentation shows that errors are also represented as JSON stream lines:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{"stream": "Step 1..."}
{"stream": "..."}
{"error": "Error...", "errorDetail": {"code": 123, "message": "Error..."}}
```

A useful tool for doing JSON parsing on the command line is **jq**. If you want only the raw (`-r`) value of the `stream` key of every line, you would do something like this:

```
curl -X POST '...' | jq -r .stream
```

This would ignore (print empty lines for) non-stream lines in the input.

For more information, see the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.19/#build-image-from-a-dockerfile) and the [jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/).